# Is a scanned copy of a passport necessary for an offer in the UAE?

Tags: job-offer, documentation, uae

Recently my friend got an offer in UAE, for release an offer letter consultancy is asking passport copy. Is it necessary to send scan'd copy of a passport for getting offer letter. And how to accept/reject offer letter.

Comment: Has the friend verified that this is a legitimate offer from a real company? Have they looked them up online, visited an office, checked what other companies say about them?

Answer (score 4):

Based on your name and profile, I surmise your friend to be relocating countries and moving to UAE.

If your friend is going for an international opportunity, obviously the company needs to see whether the friend has a valid passport for visa processing and travel, before they make the offer.

So Here, they have asked for a scanned copy of the passport, which is common for international offers.

The red flag would have been for consultancy to ask for possession of the original copy of documents, which should be a strict no, and isn't the case here.

To accept/ reject the offer, just say the same on the email, and pass back the documents required.

> Hello recruiter,
>
> Thank you for the offer details, I'm accepting it.
>
> Please find self signed copies of documents attached.
>
> Regards
>
> Friends name

Comment: I don't think the friend has the offer letter yet. My understanding is that the company wants the passport before they send the offer letter.

Comment: Sending a copy of the passport even before the offer is ok. Do not ever send original.